# How do I remove a vertex without affecting other edges and faces?

Tags: vertices, edges

I need to remove the moon shape made by vertices:[image]

But when I delete, the faces and edges remove
And when I dissolve, the edges get destroyed:[image]

I need all of those edges (and faces), but I have no idea how to do it without affecting other things

Comment: Select the bad edges (in Edge Select mode) and press Ctrl X to dissolve

Answer (score 1):

In Edit Mode:

- Switch to *Edge-Select Mode* (yellow circle in the screenshot)
- Select only the edges you want to have removed (click on one, then hold down *Shift* key to select more)
- When all edges you want to remove are seleceted, hit *X* on keyboard to delete
- a context menu will open up: Click "Dissolve Edges" to dissolve, not delete them

[image: Dissolve Edges in Edge Select Mode]